# Swift - Use of unresolved identifier 'self' / Use of unresolved identifier 'Meme' / Use of unresolved identifier 'memedImage'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I get the error message Use of unresolved identifier 'self' as well as the error message Use of unresolved identifier 'Meme'; did you mean 'time'? and Use of unresolved identifier 'memedImage' in Xcode. I am trying to make a MemeMaker and am having trouble creating a struct for  the modified image of the meme. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var topTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomTextField: UITextField!

    let textFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate()

    let memeTextAttributes:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue- 
       CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
       NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: -3.5]



    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


        topTextField.textAlignment = .center
        bottomTextField.textAlignment = .center
        topTextField.text = "Top Text"
        bottomTextField.text = "Bottom Text"

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            cameraButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            cameraButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        UIImagePickerController().delegate = self
        //
        self.topTextField.delegate = textFieldDelegate
        self.bottomTextField.delegate = textFieldDelegate
        //
        topTextField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
        bottomTextField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
        //

    }

    //Button to allow user pick an image from an Album
    @IBAction func pickImageFromAlbum(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Allows user to use camera to take a photo
    @IBAction func takeImageFromCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: 
UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: 
Any]) {
    if let pickedImage =

  info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey
(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage {

        ImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        ImageView.image = pickedImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}

func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {

    // Render view to an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.UIView.frame.size) 
    //Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
    UIView.drawHierarchy(in: self.UIView.frame, afterScreenUpdates: 
true) //Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
    let memedImage:UIImage = 
UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return memedImage
}

func save() {
    // Creates the meme
    let meme = Meme(topText: topTextField.text!, bottomText: 
bottomTextField.text!, originalImage: UIImageView.image!, memedImage: 
memedImage) //Use of unresolved identifier 'memedImage'
}

// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
fileprivate func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_ input: 
UIImagePickerController.InfoKey) -> String {
    return input.rawValue
}
```

Comment: Create iVar of _private var memedImage:UIImage!_ and declare methods _generateMemedImage()_ , _save()_ inside your _ViewController_ .

Answer (score 0):

you have declared  function in outside of the class and try to saying that this identifier is belongs to current class but there is no class for that function 
generateMemedImage()

Answer (score 0):

Let's concentrate on just *one* of the many problems with your code — the issue with `self`.

This is the structure of your code. This is *your* code; all I did here was cut most of it, leaving the structure clearly visible:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, 
    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        // ...
}

func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.UIView.frame.size)
    // ...
}
```

Your `class` declaration starts — and ends! Then comes a completely new function, `func generateMemedImage`. It is *not inside* the class declaration; it is just sitting out in the middle of nowhere. That's not illegal of itself; global functions are legal in Swift. But you cannot say `self` in a global function.

So the solution to *that* problem is to move the function *inside* the class declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, 
    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        // ...
        func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.UIView.frame.size)
            // ...
        }
}
```

Comment: This gets rid of the Use of unresolved identifier 'self' but not the error Use of unresolved identifier 'Meme'; did you mean 'time'? or Use of unresolved identifier 'memedImage'.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said at the start of my answer. Your question combined many issues; there is a _lot_ wrong with your code. My answer deals with _one_ of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help, I would first declare your Meme class or struct at the top of the page:

```
struct Meme {
    let topText: String!
    let bottomText: String!
    let originalImage: UIImage!
    let memedImage: UIImage!
}
```

Then you need to change:

```
memedImage: memedImage
```

to:

```
memedImage: generatedMemedImage()
```

Here is how you have it:

```
func save() {
    // Creates the meme
    let meme = Meme(topText: topTextField.text!, bottomText: 
bottomTextField.text!, originalImage: UIImageView.image!, memedImage: 
memedImage) //Use of unresolved identifier 'memedImage'
}
```

Here is the solution:

```
func save() {
    // Creates the meme
    let meme = Meme(topText: topTextField.text!, bottomText: 
bottomTextField.text!, originalImage: UIImageView.image!, memedImage: 
**generatedMemedImage()**)
}
```

I hope this helps.